# Accurately obtain iPhone signal strength?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cellular-network

I am currently utilising `CTGetSignalStrength();` to obtain the signal strength from an iOS device.

Whilst this function does return a value, the value appears to range from 0-45.

What does this value actually mean in terms of dBm, as this appears to be an Apple graded value that doesn't relate to an actual measurement.

Is there a way to convert the value returned to dBm, or a private API to retrieve the value in dBm

Comment: or follow http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCarrier/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: @AmiriDev Please don't ask users to work on a problem via Skype.  That makes it impossible for this question to be helpful to other users because the problem would be solved outside of Stack Overflow.

Comment: ok. But I post solution on Answer If it is working and it will be available on stackoverflow then.